# React Application Deployment Issues

Tags: reactjs, npm, github-pages

I just created a new React app and want to try deploying it first to github. In order to do that I first created the React app using `npx create-react-app my-app` then adding gh-pages using `npm install gh-pages --save-dev`. After that, in package.json I included `"predeploy": "npm run build",` and `"deploy": "gh-pages -d build",` in the scripts section and included a homepage link as well.
When trying to deploy the app with `npm run deploy` I get a error saying:

`npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE` 
`npm ERR! errno 1` 
`npm ERR! portfolio@0.1.0 deploy: "gh-pages -d build"` 
`npm ERR! Exit status 1` \

what could be the issue and how can I move forward with it?

Comment: @Bishan yes it did, thank you so much! My repo isn't private so the accepted answer wasn't it, but I tried the answer below that which suggested to set the origin and that worked for me. I didn't receive the additional error afterwards, it just ended up deploying!

Comment: Glad that I could help you